# IIS Windows Authentication - Failure 2304 on some machines

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I am working currently on an IIS server that uses Windows Authentication.

There is a weird problem for me when there are some PCs that when trying to browse to the server - they get a prompt to enter credentials instead of IIS getting that from their windows session (on other PCs - the same user can browse to the site normally - and IIS authenticates them with Windows Authentication - without the need of username and password).

I looked at the event logs - and found that and event #4625 is raised, with a failure reason $$2304.

Any ideas on what can it be? Really struggling with that, cant quite figure out why it happens..

Thanks!

Comment: Not much information here. Platform(s) and browser versions. Are the browsers configured to trust the url. A packet capture can be used to determine if the host is sending an auth header.

Comment: All PCs are running the same version of windows 10 and chrome if that helps. What info from a packet capture can I get?

Comment: ` What info from a packet capture can I get?`: determine if the host is sending an auth header.

Comment: Ever found the solution to this?